# jQuery Progress bar change value with thread

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, progress-bar

I´m working on a WebApp with Spring MVC. I have the following process: First of all the User has to upload a file. Afterwards the uploaded file will be edited.

So far the process works well. Now I want to show the user the progress of the process with a progress bar. This is my .jsp file with form for uploading the file and the progress bar:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

    <%@page import="de.pwc.logic.Constants"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.ResourceBundle"%>
    <%@page import="de.pwc.logic.TickmarkManager"%>
    <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

    <html>
    <head>
        ...

    </head>
    <body>

        <form:form modelAttribute="circleUpModel" method="POST"
            onsubmit="return checkIfPdf(this);" action="">

            ...

        </form:form>

        <div id="progressbar">
            <div class="progress-label">Loading...</div>
        </div>

    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function checkIfPdf() {
            var fup = document.getElementById('upload');
            var fileName = fup.value;
            var ext = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
            if (ext == "pdf" || ext =="PDF") {
                return true;
            } else {
                alert("Upload pdf files only");
                fup.focus();
                return false;
            }
        }

        $(function() {
            var progressbar = $( "#progressbar" );
            progressLabel = $( ".progress-label" );
            $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
               value: false,
               change: function() {
                  progressLabel.text( 
                     progressbar.progressbar( "value" ) + "%" );
               },
               complete: function() {
                  progressLabel.text( "Loading Completed!" );
               }
            });

            function progress() {
               var val = ???
               progressbar.progressbar( "value", val );
            }
         });

    </script>
    </html>
```

The corresponding controller calls a thread which iterates through the pages of the file. Whenever  the thread have edited a single page of the file the progress bar should iterate.

The problem is that I dont know how to get the current page of the process of the thread in my .jsp file. How can a thread and a .jsp communicate with each other? I think it could work with Ajax but I have never worked with ajax before.

I´m thankful for any suggestions!

Comment: websockets might be a more fluid solution if you want the server to push updates to the client. With ajax it relies on regular, timed polling by the client. Relatively expensive in terms of HTTP requests and also not as responsive as allowing the server to push data, like you can with a socket.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for the tip! I will gather some informations about websockets and how to implement it !